Rotues are not matched in Angular 17
I am new to angular.
I am trying to navigate from one page to another page in angular17. I am getting an error "Routes are not matched". Eventhough I have added the path in appropriate files.
Bloglist.component.html:
enter image description here
**
app.route.ts:
**
enter image description here

please share github repo for debugging! or a stackblitz where the issue happens!

Should be, see that it's not enclosed by [ ]. As is a literal you can remove the "binding" (the [routerLink]
   <a routerLink="/admin/blogspots/add">

See that you use the [ ] when you navigate by code in .ts, but not in .html
  navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/blogspots/add']);
  }

NOTE: Please, not attach code, instead copy the code in your question. You can formatted select the lines and use CTR+K (or enclosed all between four singles quotes

Two ways can be used:
Direct using router link: <a routerLink="/admin/blogspots/add">
Using router in ts via function:

Html Code: <a (click)=routing()>
Ts code: routing(){ this.router.navigate(['/admin/blogspots/add']); }
You need to import the router in the ts file.

